# SLES-SAP-BYOS vs SLES-SAP difference

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, suse

Could someone please tell me the difference between these two offer id when creating SUSE SAP VMs using Azure ARM template - SLES-SAP-BYOS & SLES-SAP.
I cannot find any difference except in the ARM template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BYOS = Bring your own subscription, mean that you need to buy the OS from SUSE and the VM's from Azure

PAYG = Pay As You Go, everything is sold through Azure. No subscription needed.